# What is best practice for building custom routing (.Net MVC)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

The short story is that I want to create a web app that is similar to a CMS/blog. 
The thing is that it has a page hierarchy (domain.com/x/y/z/) and it exists several controllers. I need something

1. What is best practice to handle routing like this?

   Is it to pre-register all possible paths that exists in DB, or is it best to create a
   route that fetches everything?
2. What is best practice regarding populate routeData with CurrentSite and CurrentPage object? I believe that I want to find the correct page (Based on the hierarchy and last url segment) per request and add those objects to the routeData so it is easy to get them in each controller?

Do you know any simple projects from which I can find some ideas?

Best regards